# Python array group count

Tags: python

In Python, I have an array of,

```
("192.168.1.1","high"),("192.168.1.1","high"),("192.168.1.1","low"),("192.168.1.1","low"),("192.168.1.2","high"),("192.168.1.2","medium")
```

and I need an output by showing count

```
("192.168.1.1","high",2),("192.168.1.1","low",2),("192.168.1.2","high",1),("192.168.1.2","medium",1)
```

anyone please help me

Comment: `[(*t, len(t)) for t in array]`

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried, though?

Comment: @ChristianDean it will add each element for every item occurrence , for example for  `("192.168.1.1","high",2)` it will appear two times.

Comment: **Note to answers:** Please **stop answering this question**. Questions such as this are **to broad** and should be closed as such, not answered. See [Why would a question that's normally too broad in *any* other language be okay if it's in Python?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353940/why-would-a-question-thats-normally-too-broad-in-any-other-language-be-okay-i/353947#353947) for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Counter from collections.

```
from collections import Counter

l = [("192.168.1.1","high"),("192.168.1.1","high"),("192.168.1.1","low"),("192.168.1.1","low"),("192.168.1.2","high"),("192.168.1.2","medium")]

counter = Counter(l)

result = [(*key, counter[key]) for key in counter]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about order:

```
l = [("192.168.1.1","high"),("192.168.1.1","high"),("192.168.1.1","low"),("192.168.1.1","low"),("192.168.1.2","high"),("192.168.1.2","medium")]

list(set([(*t, l.count(t)) for t in l]))
```